# Cannot get JxBrowser to render in eclipse rcp JavaFx environment

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jxbrowser

I am currently evaluating JxBrowser 6.17 as an alternative browser technology for a eclipse RCP based data maintenance application, since the SWT Browser does not suit our needs.

What are our special needs anyways? Well, we need to embed an older solution into our new application, since we would not be able to add all required features into the new application in time. Since we have the required features in an older JSP based web application we need to embed it to make the functionality available to our customers. This comes with a lot of issues, but for most of them we already generated answers. The biggest issue we are currently facing is that the SWT Browser component does not support instance based Cookies which we need, since our web application has Cookie based session management.

I have also tried using the Mozilla implementation using different profiles, which unfortunately is not possible, since the profile management is just as static as the Cookie management.

Next step is to evaluate commercial frameworks with which I am currently facing some issues.

I requested an evaluation license for JxBrowser and tried to embed it into our eclipse 4 RCP application. I would like to embed it using JavaFX, since we already use JavaFX and would like to avoid AWT.

Using the following code will instantiate a JxBrowser and load the given URL. Actually the request does get fired, but the Browser does not render any content at all.

```
FXCanvas canvas = new FXCanvas(parent, SWT.NONE);

Browser browser = new Browser();
BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);

browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com");

canvas.setScene(new Scene(browserView));
```

Even when loading specific HTML it will not render any content.

There are no observable Exceptions or errors.

Does anybody have an idea on whats the issue in my case?

In a different scenario we use the JavaFX WebView embedding the CKEditor into our application and everything works (more or less) flawlessly, but I am not able to get the JxBrowser to render its contents.

I am sure, that I am doing something wrong (probably something pretty basic :))
What could I be missing?

Any idea or tip could do the trick ;)

Comment: According to the code that you have posted, JxBrowser is running in the heavyweight rendering mode. Is the issue reproducible if you switch to the lightweight mode?

Comment: That's a good point, in fact I did not try that, but I will just to make sure whether it would work. Using the SWT_AWT bridge I was able to get everything to work as expected and it looks good so for. Thank you for taking the time